# In SSRS is there a way to use newspaper columns and still have a new page per group?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

My dataset is grouped by customer then itemtype and then the details are the itemcodes and descriptions.

I am using the Newspaper column setting so that the list of items continues on to the right side of the page instead of moving on to the next page.

My problem is that I want to start a brand new page for each customer. Since SSRS treats each column as a page break, I get a page where one column belongs to one customer and the next column belongs to another.

I have tried the page break setting on the different group and the tablix properties to try and force a double page break to happen with no luck. I have also tried to drop a rectangle into the table and use the page break setting there, also no luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Jessica

Answer (score 0):

I've not used the multi-column layout so I can;t directly comment on that but what you could potentially do is use a subreport.

If the following does not help, post a sample of your data and your current report design and I'll post a full answer.

In short, create a report that only handles a single customer, so it will need to have a parameter passed into it that identifies each customer such as a CustomerID.

Once you have the report working with a single customer, create another report.

On this report create a dataset that just contains a list of customers you want to report on (so a list of CustomerID's for example).

Add a table to the report and remove all but a single "cell". Expand this cell to be roughly the width of your subreport (it does not have to be exact).

Set the dataset property of this table to the dataset containing your list of customers.

In the remaning cell, right-click then Insert >> Subreport. This will fill the cell with a subreport control. Right-click the subreport control and set the subreport to be the sub-report we created earlier that handles 1 customer. In the parameters, set the CustomerID parameter to the field from your customer list dataset.

Finally, right-click the 'details' rowgroup and set page breaks to 'between each instance'.

This will generate one subreport per customer and put a page break between each.

Comment: I tried this but the single customer report is loosing the newspaper formatting as a sub report.

Comment: As I said, I've not used multi column format reports so it was just an educated guess. I'll see if I can get time to build a test report and update here if I do.